# Run tests implemented in C# on a multiple browsers using Selenium Grid

Tags: c#, selenium, grid

I have created test suite with 10 test cases using Visual Studio 2015. Tests are implemented in C# using WebDriver.
Now, my aim is to make a concept of distributed testing in Selenium using Grid technology.The Test suite to be run in 3 different browsers:IE, Chrome, Firefox parallely.

I think my grid setup is successful, but I need to expand my tests implemented in WebDriver. I found just a few tutorials in C# but none of them work for me ex- [site](https://seleniumautomation84.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/selenium-grid-fundamentals-implemented-in-c/). 
I would appreciate if anyone assist me in creating the tests or send me a site with tutorial in C# 
My err from executed TC in VS-[GoogleSearctTestErr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI3OB.png). 
I have one hub on a win10 machine, 2 nodes localy and 3rd node started on a VM Win 8.1 Grid console preview too-[GridConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bedU1.png)
Thank you very much.

I will add my code here:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TestOfGrid

{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Driver
    {
        IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
        capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "firefox");
        capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));


        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.56.1:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GoogleSearch()
    {
        string homepage = "http://www.google.co.uk";
        //Navigate to the site
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homepage);

    }
}
```

}

This test should be run in 3 browsers parallely. If I comment desired capabilities, the site is successfully opened, but I want to start my test on a separate browsers parallely.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have added my code, error and grid console picture. Thanks for your reply